# Error with Cas SERVICE_TICKET_NOT_CREATED and TGT trucanted with JBoss 5.1.0.GA

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, tomcat6, jboss5.x, cas

I've two webapp integrated A and B with Cas. When I try to access to protected area of webapp A the filter redirect me to cas login. After login I came back to webapp A and all works well. When I navigate from webapp A to protected area of webapp B, cas filter redirect to login form again.
I've tried this apps also on tomcat 6.0.37 and all work fine without another request of login.

Regarding the log in Jboss, I see a truncated TGT. The first time I login on cas, it write:

```
09 nov 2013 11:14:40,533 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] Added ticket [TGT-1-KYSi1x1t1MlcefajmccwatceNEqMprKj7j5ZpVDJwtJOf5OSgA-http://localhost:8000] to registry.
09 nov 2013 11:14:40,533 INFO  [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: [username: myuser]
WHAT: TGT-1-KYSi1x1t1MlcefajmccwatceNEqMprKj7j5ZpVDJwtJOf5OSgA-http://localhost:8000
ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Sat Nov 09 11:14:40 CET 2013
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
=============================================================
```

When I go from app A to app B the log is:

```
09 nov 2013 11:14:54,339 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] Attempting to retrieve ticket [TGT-1-KYSi1x1t1MlcefajmccwatceNEqMprKj7j5ZpVDJwtJOf5OSgA-http]
09 nov 2013 11:14:54,340 INFO  [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: http://localhost:8000/webappB/desktop.iface
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_NOT_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Sat Nov 09 11:14:54 CET 2013
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
=============================================================
```

As you can see, cas generates TGT:

```
TGT-1-KYSi1x1t1MlcefajmccwatceNEqMprKj7j5ZpVDJwtJOf5OSgA-http://localhost:8000
```

and attempt to retrieve:

```
TGT-1-KYSi1x1t1MlcefajmccwatceNEqMprKj7j5ZpVDJwtJOf5OSgA-http
```

I find a workaround changing the value property of bean DefaultUniqueTicketIdGenerator using from ${host.name} to a string without chars ':' and '/'.

I wouldn't change the cas configuration because it's used by a lot of applications and is deployed in different environment. 
Why cas in Jboss doesn't work as in tomcat?
Have I missed some configuration?

Comment: I've debugged cas code and the cookie was send correcty by browser. The cookie was retrieved in class org.jasig.cas.web.support.CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator using utility method of sprinframework org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.getCookie that call standard HttpServletRequest. I suppose that problem is in JBoss container and not in cas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `host.name` property is usually only used in generating tickets, and there is no requirement that it is actually the host name. It is just used to ensure that tickets are unique particularly when in a clustered CAS environment.

Try removing the protocol and port components of your `host.name` as it looks the colon is not being processed correctly on the return trip.

You can see it use in the CAS manual at https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Clustering+CAS.

Comment: This is my actual workaround but I woldn't change cas configuration.
The problem is documented here https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-7372.